# Why are Excel formulas rendered as their plain text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a spread sheet sent to me by a friend and I want to add a column with some formulas in. Instead of containing the results of the formulas the new cells contain the text of the formula. Why? How do I fix this?

Here's a simple example in which I would expect the cell B1 to contain the text `Tim` but instead it contains the text `=A1`:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I only use Excel 2003, but I suspect it's the same: you have the cell set to be a text cell rather than a formula cell. In my case I can right click on the cell and select how it will display.

Comment: Bingo! If I change the cell formatting to general and re-enter the formula it works. Thanks Xavier.

Comment: Your welcome. If you need the whole column to  be changed you can click on the column header and do the same thing rather than one at a time.

Comment: Sometimes in Excel 2013 (and maybe others) after editing the formula, the formatting snaps back to "Text". In this case, switch it to "General" again, and then refresh the formula (click on the formula text as if you want to edit it, and press Enter).